# Duvida em colisoes em javascript

Tags: javascript, jogos

estou começando a programar agora, e tenho a tarefa de fazer um simples controle com os teclados em um "mapa" que é uma imagem, e o carrinho n pode ultrapassar as ruas, o mapa é a imagem em anexo mas n estou conseguindo em pensar em uma lógica para fazer as colisoes usando as coordenadas x/y[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] as areas em verde, ou seja, tudo que nao for rua o carrinho n podera andar meu carrinho tem tamanho 40x20 pixels.

PS: Nao quero o código pronto, quero um auxilio para pensar na logica ou alguma forma mais facil de fazer que n seja usando x/y

Comment: *Colision Detection* ainda tem bastante ciência por trás, para funcionar com velocidade/aceleração, etc. Por isso depende do realismo da implementação que quer dar. Tem muito material na net sobre isso, tem até [um exemplo simples no próprio MDN para jogos 2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já fiz algo parecido com isso. Mas eu tive que criar um cenário como esse com quadradinhos, cada quadradinho representava algo que poderia sofrer colisão ou não.

No seu caso, você poderia separar essa imagem em quadrados pequenos, tentando separar ao máximo todo o asfalto. E no seu código você monta a imagem, e cada quadrado com asfalto você atribui um valor. Ao percorrer com o carro na imagem, você verifica se ela está colidindo com o valor que está no asfalto, se não estiver você não deixa se movimentar.

Existem maneiras e ferramentas mais fáceis para fazer isso, mas como é pro seu estudo, essa é uma ótima tarefa.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Entao, eu pensei em fazer assim, dividir todas as quadras em pequenos objetos e verificalar se o carrinho invade o espaço delas, usando matriz, mas o professor pediu necessariamente q fosse utilizando if testando as posicoes x/y. Porem n tenho a minima ideia de como fazer. Na correção me enganei, é pra utilizar x/y. testando toda vez que uma tecla é acionada. cima/baixo/esquerda/direita, se ele estiver proximo n deve andar. Mas obrigado! Caso consiga pensar em algo agradeço

Answer (score 1):

A partir desta imagem, gere uma nova imagem, onde as ruas são brancas e o resto é preto. A ideia é a seguinte, onde é branco, vc pode ir, onde é preto está bloqueado. Sempre que vc quiser mover o carrinho vc checa nesta imagem, primeiramente, se a nova posição continua na posição branca. Se sim, vc move, caso contrário, vc recusa o movimento (colisão)

Comment: Hmmm, é uma boa também. Obrigado! Mas já entreguei o trabalho, muito obrigado!